# Sublime Text 3 and Python 3 - exception messages

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3

I've just switched to Sublime Text 3 (from ST 2 actually) and I am getting this annoying error message when executing an invalid code. Say, I run this code (which is of course invalid in Python 3):

```
print 'this'
```

I am getting this extended error message from my Sublime:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\working.py"]
[dir: C:\Users\Myname\Desktop]....CUT HERE...
```

So alongside the exception Sublime is printing all the environment variable paths that I have. I am guessing this is abnormal behavior? or do you get this kind of error messages as well on Sublime Text 3?

If this is of any relevance, I have both Python27 and Python 33 installed, although only Python33 is put into variable paths.

Comment: To be clear, you're not asking how to fix this specific error (or more generally port Python 2 code to Python 3) but how to change ST's output on exceptions?

Comment: Yes, it's all about ST because normally ST does not thown such an error. Somerthing must be wrong there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took me too long to notice you aren't talking about Sublime's plug-in interface (that uses an embedded copy of Python 3), but about the "Build" command that just runs the file in the Python interpreter found in the PATH.

To answer your question- yes, I get this kind of messages whenever I run some code in Python that exits with non-0 exit code. Could just be:

```
import sys
sys.exit(1)
```

Change this to `exit(0)` and the output is just:

```
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

So looks just it's just Sublime's build tool trying to be helpful.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the help! And sorry If my opening post was not clear enough. btw. do you think I can automate this `sys.exit(1)` part inside of Sublime without having to type this code explicitly every time? I do not need this extended error message that Sublime build gives.

Answer (score 3):

Install the [Better Build System](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Better%20Build%20System) package. Add these settings to your user preferences (Preferences -> Settings - User):

```
"show_panel_on_failed_build_only": false,
"show_debug_text": false,
"show_panel_on_build": true
```

Answer (score 0):

According this documentation, https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function you need to include parenthesis like this `print ('this')`